# Como cambiar un punto por una coma en un numero decimal con Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string, csv, float, decimal

Soy totalmente nueva utilizando Python y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Me descargo un CSV de una URL en el que los números decimales se encuentra separados por puntos. Lo que busco es separara el decimal por comas y para ello he intentado lo siguiente:

```py
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.bde.es/webbde/es/estadis/infoest/series/be2225.csv'
myfile = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='latin-1', header=None, skipfooter=2).drop([0,1,2,4,5],axis=0).replace('.',',')
    
myfile.to_csv("downloads/bea.csv", encoding='latin-1', sep = ';', header = None, index = False)
```

Sin embargo, cunado abro el CSV no se produce ningún cambio

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Código

La forma correcta sería la siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_decimals(df, *columns):
    df.replace(dict.fromkeys(columns, {r"\.":","}), inplace=True, regex=True)

url = 'https://www.bde.es/webbde/es/estadis/infoest/series/be2225.csv'
myfile = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='latin-1', header=None, skipfooter=2).drop([0,1,2,4,5],axis=0)

convert_decimals(myfile, 9)

print(myfile)
```

La función `convert_decimals` toma un Dataframe más otros argumentos que serán las columnas a afectar y modifica el Dataframe en el lugar reemplazando en las columnas indicadas todos los puntos por comas.

#### Produce

```
                           0  ...                                                  9
3    DESCRIPCIÓN DE LA SERIE  ...  Cotización y contratación, Acciones, Sociedad ...
6                   ENE 1985  ...                                                  _
7                   FEB 1985  ...                                                  _
8                   MAR 1985  ...                                                  _
9                   ABR 1985  ...                                                  _
..                       ...  ...                                                ...
448                 NOV 2021  ...                                            8305,10
449                 DIC 2021  ...                                            8713,80
450                 ENE 2022  ...                                            8612,80
451                 FEB 2022  ...                                            8479,20
452                 MAR 2022  ...                                            8445,10
```

#### Explicación

Los Dataframes aceptan como primer argumento, entre otras cosas, un diccionario que si regex se pasa como True, debe tener la estructura:

```
{columna:{expresion regular:valor a reemplazar}, columna 2:{expresion regular:valor a reemplazar}, ...}
```

Usamos el método de clase `fromkeys` para generar un diccionario en el que todas las claves tienen el mismo valor. En este caso el diccionario `{r"\.":","}`. Recordemos que se supone que `r"\."` es una expresión regular. Lo que significa que el punto sin escapar (sin la barra invertida a la izquierda) significa "cualquier caracter", por lo que es necesario escaparlo para que represente al caracter ".".

El argumento `inplace`, si se establece en True, modifica el Dataframe original en lugar de devolver uno nuevo.

#### Nota

Durante la creación del Dataframe, te aparece una advertencia que indica que se está pasando automáticamente al motor "python" para leer el csv debido al argumento `skipfooter`. Te recomiendo pensar si ese argumento es realmente necesario. Si es necesario, puedes deshacerte de la advertencia con el argumento engine="python". Si quieres evaluar las ventajas y desventajas de usar el motor Python, te dejaré un fragmento de la documentación:

**Original**

> Parser engine to use. The C and pyarrow engines are faster, while the
> python engine is currently more feature-complete. Multithreading is
> currently only supported by the pyarrow engine.

**Traducido (con el traductor de Google y revisado por mi)**

> Motor analizador a utilizar. Los motores C y pyarrow son más rápidos,
> mientras que el motor python actualmente tiene más funciones
> completas. Actualmente, los subprocesos múltiples solo son compatibles
> con el motor pyarrow.

#### Referencias

- [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)
- [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Gracias @Dante S.